# Wrong example in Slick docs?

Tags: sql, slick

Either I am unfocused today or Slick's Getting Started docs are not well-designed.
So in the Queries/Unions section they have this snippet:

```
val q1 = coffees.filter(_.price < 8.0)
val q2 = coffees.filter(_.price > 9.0)

val unionQuery = q1 union q2
// compiles to SQL (simplified):
//   select x8."COF_NAME", x8."SUP_ID", x8."PRICE", x8."SALES", x8."TOTAL"
//     from "COFFEES" x8
//     where x8."PRICE" < 8.0
//   union select x9."COF_NAME", x9."SUP_ID", x9."PRICE", x9."SALES", x9."TOTAL"
//     from "COFFEES" x9
//     where x9."PRICE" > 9.0

val unionAllQuery = q1 ++ q2
// compiles to SQL (simplified):
//   select x8."COF_NAME", x8."SUP_ID", x8."PRICE", x8."SALES", x8."TOTAL"
//     from "COFFEES" x8
//     where x8."PRICE" < 8.0
//   union all select x9."COF_NAME", x9."SUP_ID", x9."PRICE", x9."SALES", x9."TOTAL"
//     from "COFFEES" x9
//     where x9."PRICE" > 9.0
```

And then they say:
`Unlike union which filters out duplicate values, ++ simply concatenates the results of the individual queries, which is usually more efficient.`

I think there are no duplicates produced by `q1` and `q2`. So it is either a wrong queries examples they provided to illustrate real difference between `union` and `++` or I don't get something important. Could you guys help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case there are no duplicates as there is no intersection between `q1` and `q2`. Maybe changing the queries to

```
val q1 = coffees.filter(_.price < 8.0)
val q2 = coffees.filter(_.price < 9.0)
```

would have been a better example. Anyway, **the bottom line is this:**

- `q1 union q2` translates to SQL `UNION`
- `q1 ++ q2` translates to SQL `UNION ALL`